# Understanding the functions ProjectPoints() and UndistortPoints() of OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, geometry

Trying to check if I was using correctly both [`projectPoints()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1019495a2c8d1743ed5cc23fa0daff8c) and [`undistortPoints()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga55c716492470bfe86b0ee9bf3a1f0f7e), I am obtaining results which I find hard to understand.

Having defined the following intrinsic parameters:

```py
# calibration matrix
K = np.array([
    [500.0, 0.0, 300.0], 
    [0.0, 500.0, 250.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    ])

# distortion coefficients (k1, k2, p1, p2, k3)
distCoeffs = np.array([1.5, -0.95, -0.005, 0.0025,  1.16])
```

and the following pointcloud in the camera reference (with all the points being in the same plane):

```py
# Coordinates of points in plane, representing a pointcloud in camera reference (c)
# plane
H, W = 1, 2
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-W, W, 0.2), np.arange(-H, H, 0.2))
X, Y = X.reshape(1, -1), Y.reshape(1, -1)
# add depth. Pointcloud of n points represented as a (3, n) array:
Z = 5
P_c = np.concatenate((X, Y, Z * np.ones_like(X)), axis=0)
```

I was expecting that the following process would yield the original pointcloud:

1. **Projecting** the points, while accounting for the distortion, i.e. obtaining the **distorted** coordinates in the image plane:

```py
# project points, including with lens distortion 
U_dist, _ = cv2.projectPoints(P_c, np.zeros((3,)), np.zeros((3,)), K, distCoeffs)
# projections as (2, n) array.
U_dist = U_dist[:, 0].T
```

2. **Undistort** the image coordinates to get the normalized coordinates in the camera reference.

```py
# get normalized coordinates, in camera reference, as a (2, n) array
xn_u = cv2.undistortPoints(U_dist.T, K, distCoeffs, None, None)[:, 0].T
```

3. Multiplying the previous normalized coordinates with the depth of the plane in the camera reference to get the original pointcloud:

```py
# add depth.
P_c2 = Z * np.concatenate((xn_u, np.ones_like(X)))
```

[**Complete code**]

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


# calibration matrix
K = np.array([
    [500.0, 0.0, 300.0], 
    [0.0, 500.0, 250.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    ])

# distortion coefficients (k1, k2, p1, p2, k3)
distCoeffs = np.array([1.5, -0.95, -0.005, 0.0025,  1.16])

# Coordinates of points in plane, representing a pointcloud in camera reference (c)
# plane
H, W = 1, 2
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-W, W, 0.2), np.arange(-H, H, 0.2))
X, Y = X.reshape(1, -1), Y.reshape(1, -1)
# add depth. Pointcloud of n points represented as a (3, n) array:
Z = 5
P_c = np.concatenate((X, Y, Z * np.ones_like(X)), axis=0)

# ---------------------------------------------
# PROJECTION WITH DISTORTION
# project points, including with lens distortion 
U_dist, _ = cv2.projectPoints(P_c, np.zeros((3,)), np.zeros((3,)), K, distCoeffs)
# projections as (2, n) array.
U_dist = U_dist[:, 0].T

#-----------------------------
# UNPROJECTION accounting for distortion
# get unnormalized coordinates, in camera reference, as a (2, n) array
xn_u = cv2.undistortPoints(U_dist.T, K, distCoeffs, None, None)[:, 0].T
# add depth.
P_c2 = Z * np.concatenate((xn_u, np.ones_like(X)))

# check equality (raises error)
assert np.allclose(P_c, P_c2), f'max difference: {np.abs(P_c - P_c2).max()}'
```

However, this is not true and the resulting pointcloud is significantly different than the original one.

I feel this may be due to a misunderstanding in the use of the previous functions.

Any help to understand where I'm doing the wrong step(s) is highly appreciated

---

**EDIT**

After some more experimentation, I believe the issue is with `undistortPoints()` rather than with `projectPoints()`. The latter is deterministic, while the former needs to solve a non-linear optimization problem. Emprically, by increasing the distortion, undistortPoints() tends to give worse results. However at lower levels, it correctly fixes it.

Comment: undeclared crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/understanding-the-functions-projectpoints-and-undistortpoints/10847

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, I apologize for that. no excuse but it was my first post in the OpenCV forum and didn't know the moderation was that fast, so in the meantime I cross posted here. I am going to delete this question here in a couple of minutes, while keeping it at the OpenCV forum.

Comment: keep both if you like. I'm declaring crossposts so everyone is on the same level and doesn't duplicate any effort.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz alright then, thanks. I will put links in the corresponding forum if the question is answered in either of them.

Comment: on-topic: I'd generally recommend visualizing data so it's easier to grasp and _notice patterns_, using which you can generate hypotheses as to what might be going on vs. what you expected to be going on. that's all I feel comfortable saying. the problem appears too big of a chunk for casual drive-by fastfood puzzle solving.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I see your point. I will try to invest some time on it.

Comment: you'll also benefit from simplifying. all-zero DCs, camera matrix with neat round (synthetic) values, trivial rvec and tvec, ... so you can make _small_ predictions and test them. I also wouldn't blindly trust what comes out of `meshgrid`, i.e. what order it's in and whatnot. stuff everything in a jupyter notebook and stare at numbers.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for the feedback. I am going to edit the question with maybe an explanation of what's happening. The issue here seems to be with the undistortion. With lower lower distortion coeffs, `undistortPoints()` correctly fixes the distortion (with the same code I posted). However, by increasing the coeffs., the function seems to break. This can be understood by the non-linear optimization that it needs to do in order to compute the normalized coordinates. Thanks again for your time :)